# How does minecraft and runescape validate your chat?"

Tags: java, minecraft

Basically, what I am asking is, how does a java based program with free chat gaurd against, "); String onlinejava = "exploits by closing the string."

Comment: What do you mean by "gaurd against, `"); String onlinejava = "exploits by closing the string."`"? Can you give some example? If you are asking about SQL-injection, check `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: I have never heard about Java Injection before. Maybe you could inject bytecode at runtime but this seems impossible unless the JVM uses an agent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty simple: they don't need to. Java is a compiler-language, thus the code can't be modified by this kind of exploits. This can only be done in some interpreter-languages, or before the code is compiled, like in SQL.

Comment: Thanks that gives me something to go on.